# Process (re)starting a Docker container from systemd exits unexpectedly

Tags: linux, shell, docker, systemd

I have a docker container.During the restart of the linux server docker container is stopped so in systemd, script file is added for the container restart.This script is also stopping the chef-client. But script is executing only half of the commands.I don't know why it is stopping after chef-client stop.After that it is not proceeding.

**Restart script:**

```
[root@server01 user1]# more /apps/service-scripts/docker-container-restart.sh
    #!/bin/bash


    echo "Starting to stop the chef-client automatic running.."
    service chef-client stop
    echo "Completed the stopping the chef-client automatic running"



    echo "Restart check... the Applicaiton Container  $(date)"
    IsAppRunning=$(docker inspect -f '{{.State.Running}}' app-prod)
    echo "IsAppRunning state  $IsAppRunning"



    if [ "$IsAppRunning" != "true" ]; then
            IsAppRunning=$(docker inspect -f '{{.State.Running}}' app-prod)
            echo "Restarting.... the Applicaiton Container  $(date)"
            docker restart app-prod
            IsAppRunning=$(docker inspect -f '{{.State.Running}}' app-prod)
            echo "Restart completed($IsAppRunning) the Applicaiton Container  $(date)"
    else
            echo "Restart is not required, app is already up and running"
    fi
```

**Systemctl log:**

```
[root@server01 user1] systemctl status app-docker-container.service
● app-docker-container.service - Application start
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/app-docker-container.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sun 2017-09-24 16:00:40 CDT; 18h ago
 Main PID: 1187 (docker-container-restart)
   Memory: 16.4M
   CGroup: /system.slice/app-docker-container.service
           ├─1187 /bin/bash /apps/service-scripts/docker-container-restart.sh
           └─1220 docker inspect -f {{.State.Running}} app-prod

Sep 24 16:00:40 server01 systemd[1]: Started Application start.
Sep 24 16:00:40 server01 systemd[1]: Starting Application start...
Sep 24 16:00:40 server01 docker-container-restart.sh[1187]: Starting to stop the chef-client automatic running..
Sep 24 16:00:41 server01 docker-container-restart.sh[1187]: Redirecting to /bin/systemctl stop  chef-client.service
Sep 24 16:00:41 server01 docker-container-restart.sh[1187]: Completed the stopping the chef-client automatic running
Sep 24 16:00:41 server01 docker-container-restart.sh[1187]: Restart check... the Applicaiton Container  Sun Sep 24 16:00:41 CDT 2017
```

**SystemD:**

```
[root@server01 user1]# more /etc/systemd/system/app-docker-container.service
[Unit]
Description=Application start
After=docker.service,chef-client.service

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/apps/service-scripts/docker-container-restart.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: I'd really, strongly advise not doing it this way. You'll be much better off using [systemd-docker](https://github.com/ibuildthecloud/systemd-docker) to directly map your container to a systemd service.

Comment: (You can also use `rkt` from CoreOS to run Docker images in a way that plays better with systemd).

Comment: ...even *if* you get your script to "work", it won't know when the container exits to be able to restart it (and if you want to prevent automatic restarts, you'll want to change from `Type=simple` to `Type=oneshot`). systemd and docker both play with cgroups in incompatible ways, so systemd loses track of the processes that Docker spawns.